# OS X Ignore Wi-Fi network / AP based on BSSID

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ssid

I have a situation where I have two AP's in two adjoining buildings that have the same SSID name. The problem is that the laptops that are close by are accessing the weaker AP in the other building and that is leading to connection issues. I want to be able to have a Mac OS X laptop ignore the AP in the other building.

Does anyone know if there is a way to block an AP based on its BSSID (MAC address)?

Answer (score 1):

If more than one AP is publishing the same SSID, they're assumed to be separate points of access to the same underlying networking, and clients are supposed to be able to roam freely between them. Apple provides no APIs to select or exclude APs based on BSSID.

If your clients are failing to roam correctly (or failing to pick the better choice at power-on or wake-from-sleep), then it's probably best to diagnose why that's happening. Perhaps the nearby AP is faulty or overloaded and not responding to scans (probe requests) fast enough, so clients are finding the other AP in the other building and not the nearby one.

Comment: why would that break 802.11? the client can reach multiple access points and choose one based on some criteria (strength of signal most likely). all that's being asked here is to change the criteria by which the client selects the AP. that choice wouldn't affect anyone else so how would that break anything?

Comment: @eMBee Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure why I would have said it that way when I answered this. I've deleted the troublesome sentence.